# Verifying stability of equilibria directly from the flow of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Question**: Consider the following autonomous vector ﬁeld on $\mathbb{R}$:

$\dot x = x-x^3, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Compute all equilibria and determine their stability, i.e., are they Lyapunov stable, asymptotically stable, or unstable?

Compute the ﬂow generated by the vector field and verify the stability results for the equilibria directly from the ﬂow.

My problem here is that we have gone very little into the idea of the flow of the solutions of ODEs. My instinct to find the stability of the equilibria directly from the flow of the solutions is to analyse it as we let $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$, however sometimes this is not always clear to do.

**Attempt**:

$\dot x = x-x^3 = x(1-x^2) = x(1-x)(1+x) \Rightarrow \bar x = 0, \pm 1$ being the equilibria of the system

Letting$\ \dot x = f(x)$

$\Rightarrow f'(x) = 1-3x^2 $

$f'(0) = 1$

$f'(1) = -2$

$f'(-1) = -2$

We can see here that $\bar x = 0$ is unstable, and $\bar x = \pm 1$ is stable (Lyapunov)

Calculating the flow:

$$\dot x = x-x^3 \Rightarrow \frac{\dot x}{x-x^3} = 1$$

Integrating: $$\int \frac{\dot x}{x-x^3} dt = \int \frac{dx}{x-x^3} = \int dt$$

$$\frac{1}{x-x^3} = \frac{1}{x(1-x)(1+x)} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2(1-x)} -\frac{1}{2(1+x)}$$ via partial fractions.

Thus: $$\int \frac{dx}{x-x^3} = \int \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2(1-x)} -\frac{1}{2(1+x)} dx = \log x - \frac{\log (1-x)}{2} - \frac{\log(1+x)}{2} = t+c $$ where c is a constant

Multiplying both sides by 2 and taking expontentials:

$$\frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1+x)}= e^{2(t+c)}$$

$$\Rightarrow x^2 = (1-x^2)e^{2(t+c)}$$

$$\Rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt\frac{e^{2(t+c)}}{1+e^{2(t+c)}} $$

Taking an arbitrary initial condition $ x_0 = x(0)$:

$$x_0 = \pm \sqrt\frac{e^{2c}}{1+e^{2c}} $$

Rearranging to get:

$$\frac{x_0 ^2}{1-x_0 ^ 2} = e^{2c}$$

Thus the flow is:

$$x = \pm \sqrt\frac{e^{2t}(\frac{x_0^2}{1-x_0^2})}{1+e^{2t}(\frac{x_0^2}{1-x_0^2})} = \pm \frac{e^t x_0}{\sqrt{ 1-x_0^2 +x_0^2 e^{2t}}}$$

The problem that I now have is getting an intuition and feeling of how this expression behaves as $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and how one would go about analyzing the stability directly, if I am wrong? I have searched texts however many use the notions from topology and such which I have not yet studied.

I must apologise for the formatting awkwardness in some parts.

Comment: I think the original asker's idea is the following: to the left of $-1$ the field is directed to the right and on $(-1,0)$ is directed to the left; at any rate, on some nbhd of $-1$ the field is directed **towards** the equilibrium $-1$, so $-1$ is asymptotically stable.  Then you are to check that via linearization, and via the analysis of solutions in closed form. And similarly for the remaining two equilibria.

Comment: Thank you for the response, after drawing the phase diagram I can see that the fixed points $-1$ and $1$ are asymptotically stable. We have not covered linearization only to analyse the stability from the flow, which I am unsure on how to do at this point.
One thought I have:
For a large $t$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, $1-x_0 ^2$ becomes negligible compared to $x_0 ^ 2 e^{2t}$ and thus $ \sqrt{1-x_0^2 +x_0^2 e^{2t}}$ becomes close to $\sqrt{x_0^2e^{2t}}$, eventually in on $ \pm \frac{e^tx_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2e^{2t}}} = \pm 1$ But I feel this is not enough to show if it is asymptotically stable?

Comment: The definition of asymptotic stability has two components: Lyapunov stability **and** what is called *attractivity*. As the solution for $x_0<-1$ [for $-1<x_0<0$] is (strongly) increasing [decreasing], you have practically the $\delta$-$\varepsilon$ definition of Lyapunov stability for free. Regarding attractivity (convergence to $-1$), "negligible compared with ..." is O.K. **here**, but dividing both numerator and denominator by $x_0 e^{t}$ would be more formal.

Comment: @user539887 Thank you very much for the clear explanation, I divided both numerator and denominator by $x_0e^t$ and it became much clearer that as $t \rightarrow \infty$, the expression for $\pm x$ was strictly increasing or decreasing depending on the sign. I fully understand now :)